# Blank Page even after successfully deploying on Firebase

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, deployment, hosting

Successfully deployed the project on firebase but on clicking the provided URL a blank page appears.
[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJgYz.png)

[folders and files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mY2Ne.png)

index.html is under public
but src folder in not under public.
src folder contains the assests and components of the project.
also there is no error in the console the project is working properly in the localhost without any error.

firebase.json file:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Package.json :

```
{
  "name": "poject_name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.4.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^6.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "init": "^0.1.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.27",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The `public` folder generated by `create-react-app` (CRA) is not the same as what Firebase expects the `public` folder to be. First you need to build your project before deploying and make sure that you are deploying the folder specified by the `BUILD_PATH` environment variable (if not set, it defaults to `build`) instead of CRA's `public` folder.